# Request: Glass Cracking.

Tags: glass, cracking, sound-design

Hi,

I'm on a bit of a time constraint and really need the sound of a tv screen cracking- not from an impact hit but more similar to if it was under extreme heat or cold.

Haven't been able to find anything at all- do you have something that might be able to help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have time enough to freeze water in an ice cube tray, slowly cracking that might help you to the noise you are after.

Failing that buy online somewhere like soundsnap, sounddogs, etc.

Comment: @Matt- thanks, I completely forgot that I have actually done this before for actual ice cracking - i'll try and re-find those.

Answer (score 2):

Ive found that really close miking an empty egg shell can provide the crack 'attack' sound, and maybe mixing in some other glass sounds? Not perfect, but if you're stuck, good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dominic, check my sounds.
I Think helpful.

[Glass sounds](http://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/1/membrans-glass.html)

[Ice creak](http://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/1/membrans-ice-creak.html)